# Is RenderScript the only device-independent way to run GPGPU code on Android?

Tags: android, gpgpu

Is RenderScript the only device-independent way to run GPGPU code on Android ?
I don't count Tegra as there is only few phones that have it.

Answer (score 0):

RenderScript is the official Android compute platform.  As a result it will be on all Android devices.  It was designed specifically to address the problem of running one code base across many different devices.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if it will uses gpu and not only cpu cores for a parallel for ? I could not find any confirmation on the net.

Comment: If the device has a GPU driver, it will.  Today that includes Nexus 4, 5, 6, and 10.  Many other vendors also support acceleration.  In all cases CPU will be available as a fallback.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to ask again but do you have a list of these vendors, or at least do you know if a Galaxy S4 supports it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using RenderScript doesn't necessarily mean that your code will run on the GPU. It might also use the CPU and (hopefully) parallelize tasks on several CPU cores and use CPU vector instructions. But as far as I know, you can never be sure about that and the decision process is kind of a blackbox.

If you want to make sure that your code runs on the GPU, you can "simulate" some GPGPU functions with OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders. This will run on all devices that support OpenGL ES 2.0. It depends on what you want to do, but for example many image processing functions can be implemented very efficiently this way. There is a library called ogles_gpgpu that provides an architecture for GPGPU on Android and iOS systems: https://github.com/internaut/ogles_gpgpu

OpenGL ES 3.1 also supports "Compute Shaders" but few devices support this, yet.